# Regex find commas not between quotes which may or may not contain special characters as first character in quote

Tags: regex

I have the following regex to count the number of commas contained in a string, where the comma does not appear between quotes:

```
(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)
```

For the following string, I would get 4 returned:

> a,b,c,"my my, a bit of text",e

However, if the start of the quoted string is a special character, it fails to count anything prior to the end of the quoted string:

> a,b,c,"[20200624T013030 Umognog Wrote] my my, a bit of text",e

This will return just 1

I am trying to alter it to determine all 4 occurrences in the second example, whilst not altering the results from the first example but failing miserably at the first hurdle! Regex is not my kung fu :(

I know I need to escape the '[' but I really cannot figure this out and are grasping in the dark.

Comment: Which prograamming language do you use here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the double quotes are balanced, one option is to assert what is on the right from the ***current position*** are balanced double quotes.

The newline in the character class is to prevent crossing linebreaks. You could also add `\r` if that it necessary.

```
,(?=(?:[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*")*[^"\n]*$)
```

*Explanation*

- `,` Match a comma
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `(?:[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*")*` Match 0+ times pairs of double quotes
  - `[^"\n]*` Match 0+ times any char except a double quote
- `$` Assert end of string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j490E4/1)

Comment: thank you for your reply and for solving this problem, i must say that humans in stackoverflow wins over chatGPT